# WCF service - Changing clockskew for httpsbinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service that is currently return a security exception when I'm trying to call the external server:

[image]

I've looked around and this error is often caused by a time difference between the client and the server, as the http binding in the WCF service only allows a 5 minute time difference. It should be possible to change this allowed time difference through the property MaxClockSkew, but all the guides I can find use WSHttpBinding, not BasicHttpsBinding as I use. I am using .NET core 2.2, and WSHttpBinding is not available here. Here is my binding:

```
private static System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding GetBindingForEndpoint(TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            var httpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
            httpsBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            httpsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
            var integerMaxValue = int.MaxValue;
            httpsBinding.MaxBufferSize = integerMaxValue;
            httpsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = integerMaxValue;
            httpsBinding.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
            httpsBinding.AllowCookies = true;

            httpsBinding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            httpsBinding.SendTimeout = timeout;
            httpsBinding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
            httpsBinding.CloseTimeout = timeout;

            return httpsBinding;
        }
```

Does anyone know how to change the MaxClockSkew property for this binding?

EDIT: Here is the equivalent for WSHttpBinding:

```
public static Binding CreateCustomBinding(TimeSpan clockSkew)
{
    WSHttpBinding standardBinding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message, true);
    CustomBinding myCustomBinding = new CustomBinding(standardBinding);
    SymmetricSecurityBindingElement security =
        myCustomBinding.Elements.Find<SymmetricSecurityBindingElement>();
    security.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
    security.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
    // Get the System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters 
    SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters secureTokenParams =
        (SecureConversationSecurityTokenParameters)security.ProtectionTokenParameters;
    // From the collection, get the bootstrap element.
    SecurityBindingElement bootstrap = secureTokenParams.BootstrapSecurityBindingElement;
    // Set the MaxClockSkew on the bootstrap element.
    bootstrap.LocalClientSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
    bootstrap.LocalServiceSettings.MaxClockSkew = clockSkew;
    return myCustomBinding;
}
```